# CodeIgniter + Active Record Spark save function is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

This is thoroughly confusing me.  I am trying to gather very basic statistics on my site, namely how many hits I am getting per day.

In a superclass that every controller inherits I have this code.

```
    // log every hit
    if(STATISTICS == 'all')
    {
        $stat = new Statistic();
        $stat->ip = $this->_get_ip_address();
        $stat->save();
    }
```

I am loading the spark before this block.  I do have a table setup named Statistics.  I have the Model file created named Statistic with a classname of Statistic.  Everything works well except when I try to save.

I can print out the `$stat` object and it returns an Active Record Object with everything set up properly. But for some reason when I try to call `$stat->save();` every page just returns an Internal Server Error.

I have not added a new Model to my site in a while so I may have forgotten something, but this is really bugging me.

Anyone have any ideas?

More Information:

My Statistic Model:

```
class Statistic extends ActiveRecord\Model {

}
```

Comment: Do you have an infinite loop somewhere?

Comment: I do not think so.  Definitely not one that would only be caused by saving a record.

Comment: "Internal Server Error" should create a more detailed entry in your error log that tells you where the problem is.. even better turn [error display](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) on

Comment: My error log files are all filled with timeout errors, but the timestamps are from much earlier today.  Nothing about what is happening right now.
EDIT: I just tailed my error log and no errors are being generated when the page fails to load.

Comment: can you post your statistic model here? Without looking into that file nobody can help you.

Comment: The Statistic model is an empty model that is required just to make the connection.  It is literally `class Statistic extends ActiveRecord\Model {  }`  as simple as you can get to be able to create and save records, which is all I need to be able to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that nothing was wrong with my code at all.  It all works beautifully.

Protip: Don't forget to set your id to auto increment in the database.